# bootstrap и модальное окно

Tags: html, css

Встретился с очень необычным багом.
У меня есть div блок с содержимым, под ним имеется  сама кнопка вызывающая модальное окно и само модальное окно.
При вызове ошибок нету

[image: Сам блок с содержимым, в котором находиться модальное окно]

[image: Само модальное окно]

1 скрин: Сам блок с содержимым, в котором находиться модальное окно
2 скрин: Само модальное окно

Суть проблемы в том что в родительский блок я пытаюсь добавить фильтр:

```
backdrop-filter:blur(5px) brightness(45%);
```

Но при добавлении происходит вот такая тема в случаи вызове модального окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал многие популярные способы как можно блок вернуть на место но не один не помог (z-index, position: relative и так далее) есть ли варианты в моём случаи как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен не родительский элемент, а соседский блок с тенью.

Вот пример кода с вызовом модалки и тенью.

**modal** - это сама модалка, в ней есть **shadow** - это наша тень, которая растягивается на весь родитель и имеет `z-index: 1;`, а также `position: absolution;`.

Также есть **modal_wrap** - это блок с контентом, который имеет `z-index: 2;` чтобы отображаться над тенью.

```js
$('.modal_wrap h2').click(function() {
  $('.modal--active').removeClass('modal--active') 
})

$('h1').click(function() {
  $('.modal').addClass('modal--active') 
})
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.modal--active {
  display: flex;
}

.modal_wrap {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.modal_wrap h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;  
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter:blur(5px) brightness(45%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <h1>Parent</h1>
  <div class="modal modal--active">
    <div class="modal_wrap">
      <h2>MODAL</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```